# Does TFS 2012 put Source Settings in SUO files?

Tags: tfs

I want to know where TFS 2012 puts its repository settings for a solution. I found a bunch of hidden .SUO files in my project and when I deleted them, it solved an issue where I couldn't change the TFS source server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Although binary, when opening the [.Suo file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909) with notepad you can see it contains details on the last TFS project collection and workspace associated with it. You should never check-in .Suo and .user files to TFS (or any other source control for that matter).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this in the documentation at all. It explains why I couldn't unbind my source to the existing repo without connecting to it.  A real pain.

Comment: Microsoft has a very strange way of deciding what to hide versus what to show users. They hide your outlook datafiles while letting you see your system files.